# Docker in Docker Executor in Gitlab-Runner does not work (Cannot connect to the docker deamon)

Tags: sockets, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

So i recently tried Docker and Gitlab Runner but it seems i cant get it to work.

This is the log i have:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.0.2 (a9a76a50)
on my-docker (c588e5e2)
Using Docker executor with image docker:git ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image docker:dind   ID=sha256:b9145b364a203c0afc538ca615b3470e41729edfb7338017f5d4eeb5b13b2d90 for docker service...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:7961fbf38d6f827265aed22fe41a1db889c54913283b678a8623efdda9573977 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image docker:git ...
Using docker image docker:git ID=sha256:5917639be9495ab183f357e8bafafea82449f0c4b12b745eef8bd23d474220ca for build container...
Running on runner-c588e5e2-project-1-concurrent-0 via gitlabServer...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '<Project name>'...
Checking out ed0ce69e as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ setup_docker
$ build
Building Heroku-based application using gliderlabs/herokuish docker image...
**docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.**
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

What could be the error? Docker itsself is running as it seems, but the docker inside does not seem to work.

This is my .toml file:

```
[[runners]]
  name = my name
  url = my url
  token = my token
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Edit: Thats what "docker ps" gave as output:

```
ED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
e66e844481b7        7961fbf38d6f                  "gitlab-runner-ser..."   2 sec                                                                                                                               onds ago       Up Less than a second                       runner-73520410-proje                                                                                                                               ct-1-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service
4f659dba7bac        b9145b364a20                  "dockerd-entrypoin..."   2 sec                                                                                                                               onds ago       Up 1 second             2375/tcp            runner-73520410-proje                                                                                                                               ct-1-concurrent-0-docker-0
73776d4638b9        gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-ini..."   19 mi                                                                                                                               nutes ago      Up 19 minutes                               gitlab-runner
```

Edit 2: My gitlab-ci.yaml

```
#ruby 2.2
rspec:ruby2.2:
  image: ruby:2.2
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec spec
  tags:
    - ruby
  except:
    - tags

#ruby 2.1
rspec:ruby2.1:
  image: ruby:2.1
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec spec
  tags:
    - ruby
  except:
    - tags

.go: &go_definition
  before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y ruby
  - ruby -v
  script:
    - go version
    - which go
    - bin/compile
    - support/go-test
    - support/go-format check

go:1.8:
  <<: *go_definition
  image: golang:1.8

codeclimate:
  before_script: []
  image: docker:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD" --volume "$PWD":/code    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc codeclimate/codeclimate analyze -f json > codeclimate.json
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]
```

Comment: When you've started the runner did you passed the docker socket?

Comment: where do i do that?

Comment: how do you start the runner? You don't use something like https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html ?

Comment: Like in the tutorial. I started it via docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

Comment: well as I can see from your pipeline output you are using docker:git image and the DIND service but then again docker:git. Could you put a sleep or smthg in your pipeline and docker exec into the build container that is running at the time you run the pipeline and check if you can access docker?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: in your pipeline put sleep 60 and then login on the server where your gitlab runners are running and do a docker ps and then you should see at least 1 gitlab runner container, usually there are 2 and exec in both of them 2 check

Comment: @Sergiu See edit

Comment: so have you been able to run docker inside e66e844481b7 or 4f659dba7bac?

Comment: No. Let me show you my gitlab-ci.yaml. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is my registration command, I think you are missing to pass the privileged during registration and also make sure the `gitlab-runner` user is part of the `docker` group:

```
gitlab-runner register \
  --template-config /tmp/gitlab-config.toml \
  --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "$gitlab_url" \
  --registration-token "$runner_registration_token" \
  --name "$runner_name" \
  --tag-list "$runner_tags" \
  --run-untagged="$runner_run_untagged" \
  --locked="$runner_locked" \
  --access-level="$runner_access" \
  --maximum-timeout="$maximum_timeout" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-privileged \
  --docker-volumes "/cache" \
  --docker-volumes "/certs/client" \
  --docker-image "$runner_image"

sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner

# concurrent global can't be setup in registration
# See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/332497
sed -i "s/concurrent.*/concurrent = $concurrent/" /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

# prometheus port for GitLab Runner is 9252 as defined here https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations
echo -e "listen_address = \":9252\"\n$(cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml)" > /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```